# How to mount drives at bootup as RW

Tags: xubuntu, automount

I am using Xubuntu 22.10. It automatically mounts my drives in explorer when I click on them but my backup software needs them permanently mounted so it can read the changes and I can move files to the backup drives as currently I cannot put any files into my drives as they are RO.

Comment: Add them to `fstab`.

Comment: i was hoping for a example and i thought that is what i needed to do. how do i get the volume information to add it and how do i format it in fstab last time i touched that i locked the filesystem into RO and i couldnt boot

Comment: If your drives are dropping into RO that is a sign of failing drives. It is a protection feature drive has issues stop RW.

Comment: I very much doubt every drive 8 of them are failing. i checked gnome disks and they are all mounted fine but they keep unmounting when inactive, there mounted as rw but i cant write to them